# How can I deploy vue js to my apache server? I'm using centos 9 Linux

Tags: php, linux, vue.js, nginx, centos

I want to deploy my vue.js application with API for my software. I have an API written by PHP framework.

I want to deploy my project but not found any helpful resource for the deploying. I have tried several times with the help  of NGINX and apache.

Comment: Your question is too broad and is basically asking for a full tutorial.  Stack Overflow is meant for specific programming problems or errors.  If you've tried deploying, explain what you tried and what issues you ran into.  Others may be able to help then.

Comment: I need to run a basic project developed by Vue js. I tried to deploy by nginx. but it didn't show my resource file. image and CSS/js file not found. may be an issue to link these files.